# Azure App Service Infrastructure Equivalent

Tags: azure, app-service-environment

How can I create the equivalent of an Azure [AppService](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/app-service/) using individual pieces of infrastructure in Azure?

Is there an existing ARM template that would create something similar?

Comment: Updated to be less opinionated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a quick way, you can use azure quick start and deploy the template you need:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-windows-autoscale

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates